# Category Url Issue - It changes to catalogsearch URL in fronend

Tags: magento, url

I have category url like **www.example.com/cat.html**

I have used it in one of the link in footer in static blocks.

But when i inspect that in frontend, the URL shows **http://www.example.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=cat**

I cleared the cache. Nothing happens.

I dont know why category URL changes to catalog search URL.

Somebody help me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way to add category url in your static block:

```
<a href="{{store url='category.html'}}">Link to Base URL</a>
```

That should create a link to your store's base URL.